# How to process and create an array from a MYSQL table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a website which supports user comments on posts. Their comments are stored in the database like this

```
comment1[cbr]comment2[cbr]etc...
```

in a single table column. When I read the comments from the database I just `PHP explode` at `[cbr]` to make an array. Then I post every comment using a `PHP while` loop.

Let's say I'm on `main.php?p_id=5`
PHP:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","posts");
$c_id = $_GET["p_id"];
$comment = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT a_comments FROM comments WHERE ID='{$c_id}'");
$c_array = explode("[cbr]",$comment);
$x = 1;
while(x <= count($c_array)):
echo $x . ': ' . $comment[$x] . '<br />';
$x++;
endwhile;
```

This will output

```
1: comment1
2: comment2
etc...
```

My question is, is there a simpler or at least a faster way of making an array from a MYSQL's table column?

Comment: serailize your array and save that in table and when using use unserialize

Comment: NOOOO! Make a detail table for the comments. Store each comment in a separate row. Make PostID a foreign key.